# I got animation on custom view which belongs to uitableviewcell and only the first one is working

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I've a custom view that is an `outlet` in `prototype cell`.

In the view, i make an `animation` on certain `constraint` constant.

This animation works only for the `first cell`, but not on the `other cells`.

```
override open func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.xibSetup()
    self.setViews()
}

private func animateTitleUp(){
    if self.titleTopConstraint.constant == self.titleOriginConstant{

        self.titleTopConstraint.constant -= self.titleChangeConstant
        self.title.alpha = 1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, animations:{ [weak self]() in
            self?.contentView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }
}


func xibSetup() {
    guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    view.frame = bounds
    self.contentView = view
    addSubview(self.contentView!)

}
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    setBundle()
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomPicker", bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(
        withOwner: self,
        options: nil).first as? UIView
}
```

Comment: can you show the code when you are making animation .

Comment: Along with @Vasucd, can you specify what is done in xibSetup and setViews?

Comment: @AlanS - edited, setviews sets delegates of textfields